# Alternate forms for the wave equation?

Tags: waves, notation

Are there alternate ways to write the usual wave equation?:

$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=c^2\nabla^2u.
$$

I've come across this equation in a paper (Yoshimura 1975):

$$\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial t^2}=P(\nabla\Omega\times\nabla\Psi)\cdot\hat{\mathbf{e}}_{\phi}\, ,$$

and he claims that it describes a wave (I think he forgot the unit vector in the paper). I just don't understand how... What does it really mean?

EDIT: we are in the polar spherical coordinate system. And for the purpose of this question, $P$ and $\Omega$ are just undefined scalar functions.

#### Reference

Yoshimura, H. (1975). [Solar-cycle dynamo wave propagation](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1975ApJ...201..740Y). The Astrophysical Journal, 201, 740-748.

Comment: What is this operator $P$?

Comment: Link to abstract page?

Comment: P is an undefined scalar operator. But a usual form is $r\cos{\theta}\alpha$, $\alpha$ being a time-independent scalar function.

Comment: It is hard to figure out what you are asking.  What is $P$ and what is $\Omega$

Comment: It is unimportant. They are just scalar functions (which depend on the $r$ and $\theta$ coordinates in the polar spherical coordinates). $\Psi$ is the quantity that should be described by a wave motion.

Comment: My reading of the paper is that Eq. 3.6 is meant as a very general equation from which all else follows, but the actual justification that it is a wave-type equation comes from the dispersion relationship in Eq 3.14-3.15 and the oscillating solution Eq. 3.20. (Note the sentence in the paragraphs after Eq 3.6: "The important aspects of equation (3.6) are that it is a wave equation describing either growing or decaying waves... This propagation phenomenon is rather universal and can be regarded as a theorem. In order to prove this theorem, ..." and the paper continues)

Comment: Oh I think I understand. I think I indeed read this too quickly, I thought with the theorem thing he just wanted to prove it for arbitrary coordinate systems. Well, this is what he does, but not as an additional proof. The dispersion relationship and the oscillation solution are for local cartesian units though. The thing is that equation 3.11 (his proof) has the form of a diffusion equation but with the space and time coordinates interchanged. He goes on saying that solutions to the diffusion equation have a wave structure in space with the direction given by time. I was unaware about that.

Comment: But now I see it's true. So interchanging the coordinates means that this behaviour is also interchanged and you have a wave motion. It is still curious that 3.11 is not expressed explicitly as a wave equation yet describes wave motion. I suppose that answers my question and that there are indeed alternate forms. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that that equation is an alternate form for the wave equation. It might represent a wave phenomenon, though. But then the main problem translates to define what constitutes a wave phenomenon. But I don't think that discussion so useful, at least in this context.

Let me give you an example I'm familiar with (since magnetohydrodynamics is not my field). In elastodynamics you have the following set of equations

$$(\lambda + 2\mu)\nabla(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u})
- \mu\nabla\times\nabla\times\mathbf{u} = \rho\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{u}}{\partial t^2}\, .$$

We can say that this represent "wave phenomena". Actually, it presents longitudinal and transverse waves. But this is not evident from this equation.

If we do a Helmholtz decomposition of the displacement field

$$\mathbf{u} = \nabla \phi + \nabla\times\boldsymbol{\psi}\, ,
\quad \text{with } \nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{\psi} = 0\, ,$$

we get

\begin{align}
&\nabla^2 \phi = \frac{1}{\alpha^2} \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}\, ,\\
&\nabla^2 \boldsymbol{\psi} = \frac{1}{\beta^2} \frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{\psi}}{\partial t^2}\, ,\\
\end{align}

with $\alpha^2 = (\lambda + 2\mu)/\rho$, $\beta^2 = \mu/\rho$. Here it is easy to see that they behave like waves.

Comment: Ah, I'll try that and see if that equation can be further decomposed. Thanks!

Comment: @nicoguaro do you know a good reference for this (Elastodynamics)?

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta, I think that it would be better if you ask a question for reference suggestions (and maybe tag me in the comments). Having said that, I like _Auld, B. A. (1973). Acoustic fields and waves in solids. Рипол Классик._.

Comment: I'll definitely do, thank you for suggestion and availability